# Newbie: JavaScript stops executing after I set a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax

In one HTML page I have a JavaScript function checkUpdates() that hits the server. I make this function run every 5 seconds with this line:

```
window.setInterval("checkUpdates()", 5 * 1000);
```

In Firebug, I put a breakpoint inside the checkUpdates() function. However, after the code execution stops at this breakpoint, pressing "continue" *sometimes* doesn't do anything. All the JavaScript on my page appears to have stopped.

Does this have something to do with the above line of code? Does the loop that executes checkUpdates() every 5 seconds pause when I am at a breakpoint, or does it continue running in the background? I wonder if waiting longer than the 5-second interval to press "continue" is what causes things to break.

Side note: I am new to Javascript and event-driven programming in general, so I am still a bit fuzzy on a few of the paradigms, such as whether code gets executed sequentially or concurrently. Any pointers to reading material on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the loop that executes checkUpdates() every 5 seconds pause when I am at a breakpoint, or does it continue running in the background?

Yes, it does **STOP** everything!

but soon you click "Continue" or "Play" it will resume and continue to break in the same spot (I'm guessing that you are breaking inside the **checkUpdates** method.

use the [Firebug](http://www.getFirebug.com) in order to track this, it is very easy to use.

I just made a simple HTML file so you can see this running

[There's also a screencast here](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showFlash.aspx?swf=2009-05-31_0936_soAnswer.swf&w=1000&h=620).

code : http://jsbin.com/izazu <-- remember that you can **edit** adding /edit in front of the url.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the screencast, balexandre!

Comment: no problem, glad you like it, hope you can learn from it and improve your way to code/debug :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does the loop that executes
>   checkUpdates() every 5 seconds pause
>   when I am at a breakpoint, or does it
>   continue running in the background?

I'm guessing it continues to run.

> I wonder if waiting longer than the
>   5-second interval to press "continue"
>   is what causes things to break.

That was my first guess.  It's easy enough to test - try setting the interval to 500 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Triptych. From testing, does appear to be the issue.